# Why isn't the second function working?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to make a little game but i don't have a lot of experience. Also i know that this probably definitely isn't the best way to do it, so if anyone has something for beginners that'd be great

```
<a id="key">There is a key on the floor</a>
<button onclick="keylol()">Pick it up</button>

<a id="door">You see a locked door</a>
<button onclick="doortext()">Try to open the door</button>

<script>
var key = 1
function keylol() {
document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "You picked up the key";
var key = 2;
}

function doortext() {
if (key = 1) {
document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You cannot open a locked door";
} else {
document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You opened the door hooray";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `===` rather than `=`:

```
if (key === 1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two errors:

The first one is that you're redeclaring a new variable named `key` inside the scope of the `keylol` function, therefore the value `2` isn't assigned to the outer variable named `key`.

The second one is that you're redeclaring the `key` variable instead of comparing it inside your `if` clause.

Change `var key = 2` to `key = 2` and `if(key = 1)` to `if(key === 1)`:

```js
var key = 1

function keylol() {
  document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "You picked up the key";
  key = 2;
}

function doortext() {
  if (key === 1) {
    document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You cannot open a locked door";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You opened the door hooray";
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="key">There is a key on the floor</a>
<button onclick="keylol()">Pick it up</button>

<a id="door">You see a locked door</a>
<button onclick="doortext()">Try to open the door</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a id="key">There is a key on the floor</a>
<button onclick="keylol()">Pick it up</button>

<a id="door">You see a locked door</a>
<button onclick="doortext()">Try to open the door</button>

<script>
var key = 1
function keylol() {
document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "You picked up the key";
key = 2;
}

function doortext() {
if (key == 1) {
document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You cannot open a locked door";
} else {
document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You opened the door hooray";
}
}
</script>
```